# button to scroll view. jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

i need to create a button which will be scrolling the view of website on smartphone. after click on it the view should be scrolled down, measure how far it should scroll is window height; 
html:

```
<div class="sSite">
 <a class="arrow"><img/></a>
 <ul>
     <li><img/></li>
     <li><img/></li>
     <li><img/></li>
     <li><img/></li>
     <li><img/></li>
     <li><img/></li>
     ....
 </ul>
</div>

.arrow{
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}
```

jquery:

```
var heightW = $( window ).height();
var licznik = 0;
$(".arrow").bind("click touchstart", function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : heightW
    }, 200); });
```

but it doesn't work, why?
it always scroll up to the second element li

Comment: It always scrolls to `$(window).height()`, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, so how can i write to display next part o page, to scroll down about $( window ).height(); or 2*$( window ).height(); or 3*$( window ).height(); and when there is no space to scroll one more time it shoud scroll to end of this list ul

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdr47f65/).

Answer (score 0):

I think preventing the default click behaviour should fix this and I'd use document instead of window:

```
var heightW = $(document).height();
var licznik = 0;
$(".arrow").bind("click touchstart", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : heightW
    }, 200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7wzeoyr/

Comment: but this dosnt wor like i want to, i dont want to scroll to the end of document but i want to scroll down with height of displaying window, i mean document have a lot of images, on the phone i see two or three, so i want to scroll down to see other next images